# Titanium ios and android Background state using paused and resumed listener

Tags: titanium

Working the app for iOS and Android. After login when we play in foreground using tabgroup,Gps, etc.. its functioning good.
Also after click on the Home button(Background state), if we open the app again within few mins app getting resumed.
Else we open the app later 1 hour or 1 day, splash screen shows and login screen getting open.

So I have used 'registerBackgroundService' in whome.js like below,

```
var bgService;
Titanium.App.addEventListener('paused', function(e) {

   bgService = Ti.App.iOS.registerBackgroundService({
    url:'wHome.js'
   });

   tabGrp.tabs[2].setBadge(gbc);
   etc...
}

Ti.App.addEventListener('resumed', function() {

    if (bgService != null){
        bgService.stop();
        bgService.unregister();
    }

    tabGrp.tabs[2].setBadge(gbc);
   etc...
}
```

Also below lines added in tiapp.xml for GPS,

```
 <ios>
   <plist>
        <dict>
        <key>UIBackgroundModes</key>
        <array>
        <string>location</string>
        </array>
        </dict>
    </plist>
</ios>
```

Now its seems working that the app not getting session out and resuming to whome.js screen when opening even a day after. but few second later error throwing like,

- "undefined is not an object (evaluating 'homewin.tabgroup') at whome.js (line 1)"

How to fix it and why this happening when we resumed the app. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like `whome.js` relies on a variable `homewin` which isn't available. Are you sure this variable is defined in `whome.js` and not, e.g. in `app.js` (or `alloy.js` for Alloy)? Since for the service `app.js` is not the bootrstrap, but `whome.js` you cannot use global variables defined there.

Comment: Yes the variable declared in same page. Below is some of codes integrated in wHome.js, Ti.include('wbkdatabase.js');
Ti.include('object_create.js');
Ti.include( 'searchFunctions.js' ); var Map = require('ti.map');
var homewin = Ti.UI.currentWindow;
// To check Background App register
var bgService;
var listView; var tabGrp = homewin.tabGroup; //this is the line throwing error.
homewin.backgroundColor = '#4f4b3a';
homewin.barImage = '../images/home/header.png'; In this page only I have called backgroundService for staying the same wHome.js screen. Also its contains Subviews, More UI, Maps, etc,

Comment: So you are using Alloy, but also Ti.include()? You really shouldn't use that, and the same goes for the url property of createWindow (which gives you Ti.UI.currentWindow). Both have been deprecated long and are not supported anymore and will soon be removed.